# How to cast from double to int round off the top

Tags: java, casting

I have got code:

```
double dd=2.99;
int ii=(int)(dd);//ii==2
```

I would like to have 3 in ii. Is there any fast and simple method?

Answer (score 6):

You want [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) or - if you always want to round up - `Math.ceil()`. Similarly, there is a `Math.floor()` to always round down.

Being really picky, you should note that `Math.round( double )` returns a `long`, so there is a possible loss of precision if you want to store the result in an `int` (for really large `doubles`).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.ceil(dd)`. It'll round any number up to the nearest integer. Likewise, `Math.floor(dd)` would round it down while `Math.round(dd)` would round down/up depending on which is closer.

For the record, the `Math` class contains loads of useful mathematical methods.

Answer (score 1):

**For Ceil i.e. a=3:**

```
double dd=2.99;
int a =Math.ceil(dd)
```

**For Floor: i.e. a=2**

```
double dd=2.99;
int a =Math.Floor(dd)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 double d=2.99;
 int i=(int) Math.ceil(d);
 System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use round method of java.lang.Math class.

```
Math.round(double);
```

Below is the link to API documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)